# Reserved memory in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, computer-vision

Are there any methods that we can reserve memory for GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER in OpenGL like .reserved(int) of std::vector or thrust::device_vector in Cuda?

Say, I have 200 triangles (600 indices) on frame1, but there are 250 completely new triangles (750 indices) on frame2. How can I reserved once at the beginning and update it on every frame?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have allocated a buffer object and made a `glBufferData()` call then the memory to back it is allocated. You can pass a null data pointer into the first `glBufferData()` call to make an allocate-only buffer with no data upload.

You can patch an existing buffer without reallocation using `glBufferSubData()`, however just make sure you don't try to patch a buffer which is still referenced in existing draw calls. See ...

https://community.arm.com/graphics/b/blog/posts/mali-performance-6-efficiently-updating-dynamic-resources

for more details.

Comment: thanks, but it seems like running-time increase when I reserved more memory although drawing the same number of points.

Comment: Are you sure you are definitely pipelining resource updates sufficiently (e.g. don't update a buffer which is still referenced by a draw)? If you are not pipelining deep enough then resource ghosting a larger buffer will slow things down (more memory allocation, more copies).